# modifying princeton university thesis on sharelatex

Tags: classicthesis, thesis

I want to use a customized synthesis thesis model shown in the following URL:
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/54ee3db1c592c06f6238e3a2

From this I would like to eliminate the copyright page, the contents page, the list of figures page, along with including the title 'Advisors' in stead of 'Advisor' on the title page. I have tried doing these things but I keep getting compiling errors, but i am sure this can be done. May you be willing to assist me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Eliminate the copyright page.

   The copyright page forms part of `\makefrontmatter` command. Let's see what `\makefrontmatter` looks like in `puthesis.cls`:

   ```
   \newcommand*{\makefrontmatter}{
     \bodyspacing
     \frontmatter\maketitlepage\makecopyrightpage\makeabstract
     \makeacknowledgements\makededication\maketoc
     \makelot\clearpage\makelof\clearpage\makelos
     \clearpage\mainmatter
   }
   ```

   Note how `makefrontmatter`includes`\makecopyrightpage`. That's what needs to be removed, or set to a no-op. Easiest would be to add

   ```
   \let\makecopyrightpage\relax
   ```

   as part of the preamble, just before `\begin{document}`.
2. Eliminate the Contents page.

   Similar to the above, the contents page is generated using `\maketoc`. You can therefore also add

   ```
   \let\maketoc\relax
   ```

   before `\begin{document}`.
3. Eliminate the List of Figures page.

   Similar to the above, add

   ```
   \let\makelof\relax
   ```

   before `\begin{document}`.
4. Change "Adviser" to "Advisers".

   That forms part of the `\maketitlepage` in `puthesis.cls`. It's easiest to load the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and patch `\maketitlepage` using the following:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \patchcmd{\maketitlepage}% <cmd>
     {Adviser}% <search>
     {Advisers}% <replace>
     {}{}% <success><failure>
   ```

   Again, you can place this somewhere close to `\begin{document}` document, like before.

---

Collectively, the following addition to your document preamble (just before `\begin{document}`) does what you're after:

```
\let\makecopyrightpage\relax
\let\maketoc\relax
\let\makelof\relax
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\maketitlepage}% <cmd>
  {Adviser}% <search>
  {Advisers}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

Comment: I am greatly appreciative of your help. Is there any way I can give points to your help in the above comments? I am rather new to this website, so I am not aware of this. Also, if i have any more serious problems with modifications I may not be able to work out, may I post another?

Comment: @inquiries: You can vote on my answer (the up/down arrows to the top-left of the post). If it answers your current question, you can even accept it (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)). If there are minor add-ons to the question, you can edit your post and ping me here by using an @ reply (see [How do comment @ replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/168244)), or just be commenting on my answer.

Comment: I have a minor problem with compilation of the bibliography. I get the error 'Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.' Line 3 does not contain anything pertaining to the references section, so it is rather befuddled. If you may have a chance, the link is https://www.sharelatex.com/project/54f65f3b3daa10e4172ab416

Comment: @inquiries: The only reference in `thesis.bib` is `proquest2006` and there's no `\cite{proquest2006}` anywhere in the document. Either include `\cite{proquest2006}` somewhere where it's needed/used, or add `\nocite{*}` just before `\bibliography{thesis}`, which will include all reference, regardless of whether they are cited.

Comment: I don't understand why these things need be so complicated. I am trying to change the References section the style of ApJ, so that when I have many authors it should say 'et al.'. It is giving me many error messages when I have tried to tweak a few things in a number of ways.  https://www.sharelatex.com/project/54f65f3b3daa10e4172ab416

Comment: Should you be able to look at this?

Comment: @inquiries: It's difficult because you're not familiar with the language. By "references section style" do you refer to the references at the end of the article? Surely you must, as *citations* typically have an "et al." suffix if you use three or more authors.

Comment: Yes, I refer to the references at the end of the paper.

Comment: @inquiries: For this you will need to use reference package, like [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (say) and use `\citeauthor`.